# Using Django, how to filter from an object based on FK using a column and get distinct values

Tags: django, foreign-keys

My DB query is below:

```
select distinct m.topic
from education.sessions s, education.modules m
where s.subject_id = 'Biology'
and s.module_id = m.id
and m.status = 'Active'
order by m.topic
```

I am trying the equivalent of the above in QuerySet and I do not seem to get it.First off, I do not know where to include the status='active' check and the "Order By".

Session and Module are my 2 tables with Session having a FK on module. Module has 2 columns Subject and Topic and I need the unique topics for the given subject if status = 'Active'

In Views.py, I have the below:

```
def load_topics(request):
    subject = request.GET.get('subject')
    topics = Session.objects.filter(subject=subject).values_list('module__topic', flat=True).distinct()
    return render(request, 'evaluation/topic_dropdown_list_options.html', {'topics': topics})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should help.

If the FK is on Module - then you can access the modules through the related name - it should be `module_set` if you did not define this on the field.

If I was setting this project up, I would define the related name as `modules`.

```
session = models.ForeignKey(
    "Session",
    null=True,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name="modules",
)
```

You can filter with `module_set` or if you change the related name to `modules` like so - replace `modules` with `module_set` or the related name you set up if you do not want to use `modules`

```
topics = Session.objects.filter(
    subject=subject, 
    modules__status='Active'
).order_by(
    'modules__topic'
).values_list(
    'modules__topic', flat=True
).distinct()
```

Comment: How can I get the modules.id and modules.topic in the above statement?

Comment: @Shanthi you can call `.values('modules__topic', 'modules__id')` or `.values_list('modules__topic', 'modules__id')`. Flat = True will not apply anymore. The first will give you a  queryset of dictionaires, the latter will give you a queryset of tuples with the desired values.